# How to upload photo with angular js?

Tags: angularjs

I am tryin to make an upload with angular.I am using this plunkr 
http://plnkr.co/edit/qLckEIlNLEcIfvwn4Q5x?p=preview

What should I write here If I want to upload a photo on the folder with project :

```
element.fileupload({
              dataType: 'json',
              url: './api',
              done: function(e, data) {
                $log.log("done accessed");
              },
              fail: function(e, data) {
                $log.log("fail accessed");
              },
              progress: function(e, data) {
                options.progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                scope.$apply();
                $log.log(options)
                $log.log("progress");
              },
              //add: function(e,data){
              //$log.log("add accessed");
              //},
              submit: function(e, data) {
                $log.log("notetext:", options.notetext);
                data.formData = {
                  Description: options.notetext
                };
                $log.log("submit accessed");
              }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use HTML5 API, namely `FileReader` jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/f8Hee/1/

HTML is pretty straightforward:

```
<input type="file" id="file" name="file"/>
<button ng-click="add()">Add</button>
```

In your controller define 'add' method:

```
$scope.add = function(){
  var f = document.getElementById('file').files[0],
      r = new FileReader();
  r.onloadend = function(e){
    var data = e.target.result;
    //send you binary data via $http or $resource or do anything else with it
  }
  r.readAsBinaryString(f);
}
```

**Browser Compatibility**

Desktop Browsers

> Firefox(Gecko) 3.6(1.9.2),     Chrome 7, Internet
>   Explorer* 10, Opera* 12.02, Safari 6.0.2

Mobile Browsers

> Firefox(Gecko) 32,
>   Chrome 3,
>   Internet Explorer* 10,
>   Opera* 11.5,
>   Safari 6.1

*Note : readAsBinaryString() method is deprecated and [readAsArrayBuffer()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) should be used instead.*

Happy Helping!

Comment: yes but can you help me that example to work please?

Comment: @CarmenMitru You're going to have to tell us what you mean by getting that example to work.  This is the complete code you need; you just add your own hook to your server side call that accepts a POST and is listening for this file.

Comment: I asked what should I write on url .In the example they say  url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/',.What should I write in order to upload files in my project folder.shoudl I write  url: './',

Comment: @CarmenMitru if you need baby steps to learn follow this link: https://github.com/leon/angular-upload and this is good video tutorial: https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-file-uploads

Comment: I ask you again,maybe you didn't understand! What shoul I write on url in order to upload file in my folder .I tried this "./" but it says fails accessed

Comment: I have this line : `url: '//jquery-file-upload.appspot.com/'`.

What should I change here to upload the file in my project folder.I tried url :"./".but it won't work.


What shoul I write?

Comment: @CarmenMitru the very first thing you should do is just relax man! no worries :) its normal in development to have such situations- the second thing url should be the target location where your image/file will be saved, in normal cases its server endpoint i.e. node.js -- for example http://localhost:3000/profile-pics is the url where image/file will be uploaded

Comment: You don't understand!I dont;t want to use node js! Next I ask again : WHAT should I write there in url  to upload in my folder.For example my project is called demo and I want to upload the file in img.Should I write THERE in url "demo/images" ?

Comment: If I were you I'd calm down and asking nicely, otherwise you might receive no answer at all! Perhaps you should consider that it's you that don't understand, not the guys who are trying to help you out! Just a tip, anyway. Best of luck!

Comment: Of course you get angry when you ask a question third time but nobody answear to that particular question.It's like asking you what's  your name and you keep repeating me "Hello".....

Comment: @VirtuaCreative you are right on the money!! But I understand the state Carmen is passing from, I think she must see the video tutorial I have shared at least so that she has some idea about uploading. And after that she will be confident on asking same question but with clear mind.

Comment: Take it easy folks! We are all grown up guys trying to help each other! Carmen, calm down and follow the steps that Zeeshan gave to you; perhaps your answer is there! And if it's not, you might finding another way to make your question. Anyway, I can't help you as I don't know how to do what you need, I was just passing by and thought that I might help you to chill so you could achieve what you need! All the best for you all! :D